# Config.js file in django-ckeditor not applying configurations

Tags: javascript, django, ckeditor

I have been trying to style Django-CKEditor by modifying the `config.js` file, all to no avail; my custom configuration in `config.js` is not working. I have gone as far as manually modifying the default CSS files, but all these modifications fail to work as well. Although when I use Chrome's `developers tool` to make some modifications, they all worked. My question is, is the `config.js` file not usable in Django?

`config.js`

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.uiColor = '#000000';
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    config.width = "100%";
    config.height = "300";
    config.extraPlugins = 'autogrow';
    config.autoGrow_minHeight = 250;
    config.autoGrow_maxHeight = 600;
};
```

`settings.py`

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "images/avatar/"
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'

CKEDITOR_RESTRICT_BY_USER = True
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'moono-lisa',
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ],
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles']},
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
             'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline']},
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor']},
            {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
            {'name': 'insert', 'items': ['Smiley']},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
    },
}
```

`HTML`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js' %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who might come across the same issue, there is no need to modify the `config.js` file in your `Django` app except you have more advanced options to work with. In the simplest form, you can simply make the modifications within the `CKEDITOR_CONFIGS` settings in your `settings.py` file.

See a sample of my modifications below.

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ],
        'width': 'auto',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
         ...more settings...
        ],
        'toolbar': 'Custom',

        # more custom settings
        'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
        'uiColor': '#f4f5f7',
    },
}
```